# Answering my own question that's on hold

Tags: support, on-hold, bad-questions

I asked a poor, un-SO-like question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130305/static-member-functions-a-good-idea) that was put on hold for good reason. However, the question was indirectly answered in the comments, and I'd like to "answer" my own question in an effort to close it, mark it as done, prevent further downvoting, etc. (The latter is a joke)

Is this something I can do? Should I wait until the edit is seen? Or should the question be closed without an answer?

Comment: Your question will only be re-opened when it meets the site standards (edit it, your first edit will push it into review). Prior to that, noone can nor should answer. If you cannot bring it up to snuff, it will be roomba'd (unless you delete it yourself) soon enough. Keep in mind that all your past contributions are considered for posting priviliges...

Comment: @Deduplicator Fair enough. Since the question doesn't really lend itself to being reworded to fit the site's standards, I've deleted it. Also, what did you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: Well, there are rate limits for most things on the site, which scale with past evidence (reputation, closed/deleted/downvoted/upvoted posts). At the worst end, one runs into post-bans. But if most of your questions are well-received, you can simply forget about the few bad spots.

Comment: Oh, true. I just don't like having a bad question looming over my head, it's not good for my ego :-) Thanks for the response.